# Jquery did not finish populate field

Tags: javascript, jquery

It stops anywhere in the .done() code. Sometimes it works well after I clean cache or I have to refresh a few times to make the population of form completed.
These codes are in my javascript file and my php file.

```js
$(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
      });


      function getData(id) {
        $.getJSON('process.php', {
            action: "lookup",
            id: id
          })
          .done(function(data) {
            if (data.id > 0) {

              $('#txtaction').val('update');
              $('#txtaction2').val('new');
              $('#txtaction3').val('new');
              $('#txtaction4').val('new');
              $('#txtaction_ex_cost').val('new_cost');
              $('#txtaction_im_cost').val('new_cost');
              $('#txtjob_id').val(data.id);
              $('#txtjob_id2').val(data.id);
              $('#txtjob_id3').val(data.id);
              $('#txtjob_id4').val(data.id);
              $('#txtjob_id_ex_cost').val(data.id);
              $('#txtjob_ref').val(data.job_ref);
              $('#txtbranch').val(data.branch);
              $.getJSON('process.php?action=getUserBranch', function(branch_data) {
                if (branch_data == "") {
                  // HQ : enable select
                  $('label[for="txtbranch"]').show();
                  $('#txtbranch').show();
                } else {
                  // disable select
                  $('label[for="txtbranch"]').hide();
                  $('#txtbranch').hide();

                }
              });

              $('#txttradelane').val(data.tradelane);
              $('#txtshipment_type').val(data.shipment_type);

              if (data.shipment_type == "EX") document.getElementById('lbl_txtport').innerHTML = "<b>POL Code</b>";
              else document.getElementById('lbl_txtport').innerHTML = "<b>POD Code</b>";
              $('#txtcompany').val(data.company);
              $('#txtstatus').val(data.status);
              $('#txtdata_status').val(data.status);
              $('#txtmode').val(data.mode);
              $('#txtport').val(data.port_code);
              $('#txtport_name').val(data.port_name + ', ' + data.country_name);
              $('#txtvessel').val(data.vessel_code);
              $('#txtvessel_name').val(data.vessel_name);
              $('#txtvoyage_no').val(data.voyage_no);
              $('#txtclosing_datetime').val(data.closing_datetime);
              $('#txtport_vessel_code').val(data.port_vessel_code);
              $('#txtsa').val(data.sa_code);
              $('#txtsa_name').val(data.sa_name);
              $('#txtpsa').val(data.psa_code);
              $('#txtpsa_name').val(data.psa_name);
              $('#txtscn').val(data.scn);
              $('#txtka_no').val(data.ka_no);
              $('#txtopr_code').val(data.opr_code);
              if (data.nil_manifest == 1)
                $('#txtnil_manifest').prop('checked', true);
              else
                $('#txtnil_manifest').prop('checked', false);


              if (data.shipment_type == "EX") {
                //document.getElementById('lbl_txtport').innerHTML = "<b>POL Code</b> (Type name/code to search)";
                //document.getElementById('lbl_txtport_name').innerHTML = "<b>POL Name</b>";
                $('#txtpol_code').attr("readonly", true);
                $("#txtpol_code").addClass("readonly");
                $('#txtpod_code').attr("readonly", false);
                $("#txtpod_code").removeClass("readonly");
                $('#txtpol_code').val(data.port_code);
                $('#txtpol_name').val(data.port_name + ', ' + data.country_name);
                $('#txtpod_code').val("");
                $('#txtpod_name').val("");
                $("select#txtpod_terminal").html("");
                $("select#txtpod_terminal").removeClass("text");
                $("select#txtpod_terminal").addClass("text");

              } else {
                if (data.shipment_type == "IM") {
                  //document.getElementById('lbl_txtport').innerHTML = "<b>POD Code</b> (Type name/code to search)";
                  //document.getElementById('lbl_txtport_name').innerHTML = "<b>POD Name</b>";
                  $('#txtpol_code').attr("readonly", false);
                  $("#txtpol_code").removeClass("readonly");
                  $('#txtpod_code').attr("readonly", true);
                  $("#txtpod_code").addClass("readonly");
                  $('#txtpol_code').val("");
                  $('#txtpol_name').val("");
                  $('#txtpod_code').val(data.port_code);
                  $('#txtpod_name').val(data.port_name + ', ' + data.country_name);
                  $("select#txtpol_terminal").html("");
                  $("select#txtpol_terminal").removeClass("text");
                  $("select#txtpol_terminal").addClass("text");
                }
              }

              var options = '<option value="">&nbsp;</option>';
              $.getJSON('../../search/terminalByPort.php', {
                port: data.port_code
              }, function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  options += '<option value="' + data[i].label + '">' + data[i].value + '</option>';
                }
                if ($("#txtshipment_type").val() == "EX") {
                  $("select#txtpol_terminal").html(options);
                  $("select#txtpol_terminal").removeClass("text");
                  $("select#txtpol_terminal").addClass("text");
                } else {
                  $("select#txtpod_terminal").html(options);
                  $("select#txtpod_terminal").removeClass("text");
                  $("select#txtpod_terminal").addClass("text");
                }
              });

              $('#pol_list').load('pol_list.php?job_id=' + data.id);
              $('#pod_list').load('pod_list.php?job_id=' + data.id);
              $('#ts_list').load('ts_list.php?job_id=' + data.id);

              if (data.shipment_type == 'EX' && data.job_ref != "") {
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(1)').show();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(2)').show();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(3)').show();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(4)').show();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(5)').show();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(6)').hide();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(7)').hide();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(8)').hide();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(9)').hide();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(10)').show();
                $('#tabs ul > li:eq(11)').hide();
              } else {
                if (data.shipment_type == 'IM' && data.job_ref != "") {
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(1)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(2)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(3)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(4)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(5)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(6)').show();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(7)').show();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(8)').show();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(9)').show();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(10)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(11)').show();
                } else {
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(1)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(2)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(3)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(4)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(5)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(6)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(7)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(8)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(9)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(10)').hide();
                  $('#tabs ul > li:eq(11)').hide();
                }
              }

              if (data.status == "OPEN") {
                if (data.job_ref == "") {
                  $("#formdiv :input").attr("disabled", false);
                } else {
                  $("#formdiv :input").attr("disabled", false);
                  $("#txtshipment_type").attr("disabled", true);
                  $("#txttradelane").attr("disabled", true);
                  $("#txtmode").attr("disabled", true);
                  $("#txtport").attr("disabled", true);
                }
                $("#txtvessel_code").select().focus();
              } else {
                if (data.status == "CANCELED") {
                  $("#formdiv :input").attr("disabled", true);
                } else {
                  if (data.status == "CONFIRMED") {
                    $("#formdiv :input").attr("disabled", true);
                  }
                }
              }
              $('#txtaction').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtaction2').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtaction3').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtaction4').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtstatus').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtdata_status').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtjob_id').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtjob_id2').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtjob_id3').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtjob_id4').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtjob_pol_id').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtjob_pod_id').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtsa_name').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#txtpsa_name').attr("disabled", false);
              $('#btn_save2').attr("disabled", false);
              $("#booking :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#cmo :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#bl :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#bl_billing :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#bl_container :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#do_container :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#do :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#do_billing :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#do_equip_billing :input").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#btn_edit_ex_cost").attr("disabled", false);
              $("#btn_edit_im_cost").attr("disabled", false);
              $('#btn_delete').attr('disabled', false);

            }
          });
      }
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post" name="form1">

  <div class="sixper">
    <label for="txtaction">Action
      <input type="text" name="txtaction" id="txtaction" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>

    <input type="hidden" name="txtjob_id" id="txtjob_id" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>

    <label for="txtjob_ref">Job Ref
      <input type="text" name="txtjob_ref" id="txtjob_ref" maxlength="15" class="text readonly" Readonly />
    </label>

    <label for="txtopr_code">Operator Code
      <input type="text" name="txtopr_code" id="txtopr_code" class="text readonly" Readonly />
    </label>

    <label for="txtcompany">Company
      <input type="text" name="txtcompany" id="txtcompany" class="text readonly" Readonly />
    </label>

    <label for="txtbranch">Branch
      <select name="txtbranch" id="txtbranch">
        <?php try { $dbh=D atabaseHelpers::getDatabaseConnection(); $stmt=$ dbh->prepare('SELECT * ' . 'FROM branch ' . 'ORDER BY branch_name'); $success = $stmt->execute(); if ($success) { while ($branch_result = $stmt->fetch()){ printf ("
        <option value='%s'>%s</option>",$branch_result['branch_code'], $branch_result['branch_name']); } } $dbh = null; } catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } ?>
      </select>
    </label>

  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="sixper">

    <label for="txtmode">Shipment Mode
      <select NAME='txtmode' id="txtmode" title="Shipment Mode" class="text">
        <?php try { $dbh=D atabaseHelpers::getDatabaseConnection(); $stmt=$ dbh->prepare('SELECT distinct(bt_type) ' . 'FROM book_type ' . 'ORDER BY bt_type'); $success = $stmt->execute(); if ($success) { while ($booking_type_result = $stmt->fetch()){ printf ("
        <option value='%s'>%s</option>",$booking_type_result['bt_type'], $booking_type_result['bt_type']); } } $dbh = null; } catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } ?>
      </select>
    </label>

    <label for="txtshipment_type">Shipment Type
      <select NAME='txtshipment_type' id="txtshipment_type" title="Import / Export" class="text">
        <option value="EX">EXPORT</option>
        <option value="IM">IMPORT</option>
      </select>
    </label>

    <label for="txtport"><span id="lbl_txtport">POL Code</span>
      <input type="text" name="txtport" id="txtport" maxlength="10" class="text" />
    </label>

    <label for="txtport_name">Port Name
      <input type="text" name="txtport_name" id="txtport_name" class="text readonly" Readonly />
    </label>

    <label for="txttradelane">Tradelane
      <select NAME='txttradelane' id="txttradelane" title="Tradelane" class="text">
        <option value=''>&nbsp;</option>
        <?php try { $dbh=D atabaseHelpers::getDatabaseConnection(); $stmt=$ dbh->prepare('SELECT * ' . 'FROM tradelane ' . 'ORDER BY tradelane_name'); $success = $stmt->execute(); if ($success) { while ($tradelane_result = $stmt->fetch()){ printf ("
        <option value='%s'>%s</option>",$tradelane_result['tradelane_abbrev'], $tradelane_result['tradelane_name']); } } $dbh = null; } catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } ?>
      </select>
    </label>

    <label for="txtstatus">Status
      <select NAME='txtstatus' id="txtstatus" title="Job Status" class="text">
        <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
        <option value="CONFIRMED">CONFIRMED</option>
        <option value="CANCELED">CANCELED</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="txtdata_status" id="txtdata_status">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <br clear="LEFT">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#job_info">Job Info</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#booking" class="booking_list">Booking</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#cmo" class="cmo_list">CMO</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#bl" class="bl_list">Bill of Lading</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#bl_billing" class="bl_billing_list">Billing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#bl_container" class="bl_container_list">Container Movement</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#do" class="do_list">Delivery Order</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#do_billing" class="do_billing_list">Billing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#do_equip_billing" class="equip_billing_list">Equipment Billing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#do_container" class="do_container_list">Container Movement</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#ex_costing" class="ex_costing_list">Costing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#im_costing" class="im_costing_list">Costing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <DIV class="ui-layout-content ui-widget-content" style="width:100%;height:470px;overflow-x: hidden !important; ">

    <div id="job_info">

      <div class="fourper">
        <label for="txtvessel">Vessel / Flight Code
          <input type="text" name="txtvessel" id="txtvessel" class="text" placeholder="Type & Select" />
        </label>

        <label for="txtvessel_name">Vessel / Flight Name
          <input type="text" name="txtvessel_name" id="txtvessel_name" class="text readonly" READONLY />
        </label>

        <label for="txtvoyage_no">Voyage / Flight No
          <input type="text" name="txtvoyage_no" id="txtvoyage_no" maxlength="10" class="text" />
        </label>

        <label for="txtport_vessel_code">Port Vessel Code
          <input type="text" name="txtport_vessel_code" id="txtport_vessel_code" maxlength="5" class="text readonly" READONLY />
        </label>

      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>

      <div class="fourper">
        <label for="txtpsa">Principal Shipping Agent Code
          <input type="text" name="txtpsa" id="txtpsa" class="text" placeholder="Type & Select" />
        </label>

        <label for="txtpsa_name">Principal Agent Name
          <input type="text" name="txtpsa_name" id="txtpsa_name" class="text readonly" READONLY />
        </label>

        <label for="txtsa">Shipping Agent Code
          <input type="text" name="txtsa" id="txtsa" class="text" placeholder="Type & Select" />
        </label>

        <label for="txtsa_name">Shipping Agent Name
          <input type="text" name="txtsa_name" id="txtsa_name" class="text readonly" READONLY />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>

      <div class="fourper">
        <label for="txtclosing_datetime">Closing Date Time
          <input type="text" name="txtclosing_datetime" id="txtclosing_datetime" maxlength="25" class="text" />
        </label>

        <label for="txtscn">SCN
          <input type="text" name="txtscn" id="txtscn" maxlength="10" class="text" />
        </label>

        <label for="txtka_no">KA No.
          <input type="text" name="txtka_no" id="txtka_no" maxlength="10" class="text" />
        </label>

        <label for="txtnil_manifest">
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="txtnil_manifest" id="txtnil_manifest" value="1" />&nbsp;Nil Manifest <i>(EDI Purpose)</i>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <br clear="LEFT">
      <br clear="LEFT">

      <span class="sub-section">Please save before proceeding to next section</span>
      <div class="oneper">
        <p align="center">
          <button type="button" class="button" id="btn_save2" name="btn_save2" Title="Save" style="cursor:pointer;border:none;padding: 5px;margin:2px;">
            <img src="../../images/icon/save2.gif" alt="Save">
            <br>Click to save data above
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <br clear="LEFT">
      <br clear="LEFT">
</form>

<span class="section">POL Terminal</span>

<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<!--  Comment************************************************************ -->
<!--  ***************** PORT VESSEL ID ********************************** -->
<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<form method="post" name="form2_1" id="form2_1">
  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtaction2">Action
      <input type="text" name="txtaction2" id="txtaction2" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>

    <label for="txtjob_id2">Job ID
      <input type="text" name="txtjob_id2" id="txtjob_id2" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>

    <label for="txtjob_pol_id">Job POL ID
      <input type="text" name="txtjob_pol_id" id="txtjob_pol_id" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtpol_code">POL Code
      <input type="text" name="txtpol_code" id="txtpol_code" maxlength="10" class="text" placeholder="Type & Select" />
    </label>

    <label for="txtpol_name">POL NAME
      <input type="text" name="txtpol_name" id="txtpol_name" class="text readonly" Readonly />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtpol_terminal">Terminal
      <select NAME='txtpol_terminal' id="txtpol_terminal" title="POL Terminal">

      </select>
    </label>
    <label for="txteta_pol">ETA POL
      <input type="text" name="txteta_pol" id="txteta_pol" maxlength="12" class="text" />
    </label>

    <label for="txtetd_pol">ETD POL
      <input type="text" name="txtetd_pol" id="txtetd_pol" maxlength="12" class="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>


  <div class="oneper">
    <p align="center">
      <button type="button" name="btn_save_pol" id="btn_save_pol" title="Save POL" class="cssbutton">
        <img src="../../images/icon/save.gif" alt="Save">Save POL
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <br clear="LEFT">
  <br clear="LEFT">

  <div id="pol_list"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <br clear="LEFT">
  <br clear="LEFT">
</form>

<span class="section">POD Terminal</span>

<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<!--  Comment************************************************************ -->
<!--  ***************** POD & Terminal ********************************** -->
<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<form method="post" name="form2_2" id="form2_2">
  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtaction3">Action
      <input type="text" name="txtaction3" id="txtaction3" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>

    <label for="txtjob_id3">Job ID
      <input type="text" name="txtjob_id3" id="txtjob_id3" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>

    <label for="txtjob_pod_id">Job POD ID
      <input type="text" name="txtjob_pod_id" id="txtjob_pod_id" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtpod_code">POD Code
      <input type="text" name="txtpod_code" id="txtpod_code" maxlength="10" class="text" placeholder="Type & Select" />
    </label>

    <label for="txtpod_name">POD NAME
      <input type="text" name="txtpod_name" id="txtpod_name" class="text readonly" Readonly />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtpod_terminal">POD Terminal
      <select NAME='txtpod_terminal' id="txtpod_terminal" title="POD Terminal">
      </select>
    </label>
    <label for="txteta_pod">ETA POD
      <input type="text" name="txteta_pod" id="txteta_pod" maxlength="12" class="text" />
    </label>

    <label for="txtetd_pod">ETD POD
      <input type="text" name="txtetd_pod" id="txtetd_pod" maxlength="12" class="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>


  <div class="oneper">
    <p align="center">
      <button type="button" name="btn_save_pod" id="btn_save_pod" title="Save POD" class="cssbutton">
        <img src="../../images/icon/save.gif" alt="Save">Save POD
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <br clear="LEFT">
  <br clear="LEFT">

  <div id="pod_list"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <br clear="LEFT">
  <br clear="LEFT">
</form>


<span class="section">Transhipment Terminal</span>

<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<!--  Comment************************************************************ -->
<!--  ***************** TRANSHIPMENT & Terminal ************************* -->
<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<!--  ******************************************************************* -->
<form method="post" name="form2_3" id="form2_3">
  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtaction4">Action
      <input type="text" name="txtaction4" id="txtaction4" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>

    <label for="txtjob_id4">Job ID
      <input type="text" name="txtjob_id4" id="txtjob_id4" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>

    <label for="txtjob_ts_id">Job TS ID
      <input type="text" name="txtjob_ts_id" id="txtjob_ts_id" class="text readonly" ReadOnly>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtts_code">T/S Code
      <input type="text" name="txtts_code" id="txtts_code" maxlength="10" class="text" placeholder="Type & Select" />
    </label>

    <label for="txtts_name">Transhipment Port NAME
      <input type="text" name="txtts_name" id="txtts_name" class="text readonly" Readonly />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="fourper">
    <label for="txtts_terminal">Transhipment Terminal
      <select NAME='txtts_terminal' id="txtts_terminal" title="TS Terminal">
      </select>
    </label>
    <label for="txteta_ts">ETA Transhipment Port
      <input type="text" name="txteta_ts" id="txteta_ts" maxlength="12" class="text" />
    </label>

    <label for="txtetd_ts">ETD Transhipment Port
      <input type="text" name="txtetd_ts" id="txtetd_ts" maxlength="12" class="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>


  <div class="oneper">
    <p align="center">
      <button type="button" name="btn_save_ts" id="btn_save_ts" title="Save Transhipment" class="cssbutton">
        <img src="../../images/icon/save.gif" alt="Save">Save Transhipment Port
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <br clear="LEFT">
  <br clear="LEFT">

  <div id="ts_list"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <br clear="LEFT">
  <br clear="LEFT">
</form>
</div>
```

Hope anybody can help.

Comment: Open developer tools and see whether javascript error occured.

Comment: Or create a jsfiddle/codepen that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply but there's no error shows.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line of code first in your script:

```
         $.getJSON('process.php?action=lookup&fixed_item_id='+id, parseInfo);
```

Does the parseInfo function call enclose the value of fixed_item_id value in  ' ' ?  If not 
you may be missing the closing ' and the browser could be encoding your url in a manner that is undesirable to you.

Comment: Thanks Larry. The code executed "if (data.id > 0) {}".
txtaction, txtfixed_item_id, txtport, txtport_name, txttradelane_id has the correct data and it's attribute is set correctly
After this, the subsequent fields (txtcharge_id, txtshipment_type, txtloading_type, txtbooking_type, txttypesize, txtsales_cost, txtfeeder_operator, txtagent_code, txtagent_name) are not populate with data and it's not set to disabled. It looks like execution stop halfway. It happens randomly. I have to refresh for a few times to make it display properly.
Anyway I'll try to recheck all my codings again.

Comment: maybe your browser or server cache was refreshed?

Comment: I always have $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }) in the beginning of my script. Does this affect? 
I have other modules which calling table using statement like this: $('#list2').load('list2.php?t='+tradelane+'&quote_id=0'); sometimes the table does not appear. I have to refresh the page a few times then only it will appear. All happen randomly.

Comment: I have changed to this:
function getData(id) {
 $.getJSON('process.php', {
    action : "lookup",
  id     : id 
 })
  .done(function( data ) {
   if (data.id > 0) {
           //populate form
        }
  });
}

So far I have not facing any problem yet.

Comment: Thats good it sounds like the done function is what you needed. I am just curious, why do you need the the return false in your code?

Comment: I'm actually a newbie in jquery. I copied the method from somewhere which I could not remember and modified it to suit my requirements. Never really go find out why is there a return false needed in the script. :D  Thanks for pointing out Larry!! I'm so grateful...

Comment: no problem, return false is often used to exit a function or loop for example. An example would be looping through an array and then exiting the loop using return false when have found the item you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! I'll keep it in my mind. I'll go through all the modules again to make sure I'm using it at the correct place!

Comment: oh gosh... .done() still did not solve my problem. It still stopped halfway.

Comment: can you post the php code that produces the json and the html form you want to populate the data with and I can try and figure out what is going on? It looks like you are using a controller of some sort, by the looks of your url in you getJSON function.  If you can just provide the the json produced by the php file and the html form you are using it might be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: hmm... it's a bit long to post it right here. Possible you download the files from here:
[link](https://portal.sfreight.com/portal/operation/job/form.php.txt)
[link](https://portal.sfreight.com/portal/operation/job/form.js.txt)
[link](https://portal.sfreight.com/portal/operation/job/process.php.txt)
Merry Christmas to you @Larry!

Comment: I will check it out as soon as I can, Merry Christmas to you as well.

Comment: Your link has a bad security certificate can you post the html form you are using?

Comment: {"id":"1","job_ref":"11BA501001","shipment_type":"EX","vessel_code":"T14020","vessel_name":"TEERA BHUM","voyage_no":"111","port_code":"MYPKG","port_name":"PORT KLANG","port_vessel_code":"T1263","mode":"NVO","country_name":"MALAYSIA","sa_code":"BS0139","sa_name":"SEASWIFT SHIPPING & FORWARDING S\/B","psa_code":"BS0397","psa_name":"ANL","scn":"11","ka_no":"11","closing_datetime":"31-12-2014 00:00","status":"CONFIRMED","tradelane":"SPARROW","company":"SPARROW","opr_code":"","branch":"11","nil_manifest":"0","slot_owner_code":"","slot_owner_name":"","carrier_code":"","carrier_name":""}

Comment: Hi @Larry. Thanks for your reply! I've edited my post to show my codes. and the json return as in my comment above.

Comment: Were is the input element txtcharge_id? This is where you stated that bug begins to take place and I searched your html and it appears no where in the form.

Comment: Oops... I posted the wrong module. This problem happens in most of the modules, even if the form has only 10 fields. Anyway I'll try using Firefox from now on to see whether the problem persists. Sorry for bugging you @Larry, and thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: Good luck, I tested your json and it looks good but for some reason  it doesn't like the   "opr_code" property.  Even though it looks correct you might try removing it and see if anything changes.

Comment: Thanks for your further testing @Larry! Really appreciate that!